# wp_insert_post with custom taxonomy

Tags: php, wordpress

I registered a custom taxonomy with this code:

```
register_taxonomy( 'user_r_category', array( 'user_r' ), $args );
```

Now I try to insert a post to 'user_r_category' taxonomy within the category ID 7 and the post_type 'user_r':

```
$new_post = array(
          //'ID' => '',
          'post_author' => $current_user->ID, 
          //'post_category' => array(7),
          'post_type'   => 'user_r',
          'post_content' => $r_textarea, 
          'post_title' => $r_title,
          'tax_input'    => array(
                            'user_r_category' => array( 7 )
                        ),
          'post_status' => 'publish'
        );

    $post_id = wp_insert_post($new_post);
```

The post was created, but not with the category 7. How could this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to use:

1- [**get_term_by**](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_by)  to get term obj 
2- [**wp_set_object_terms**](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_set_object_terms) to set custom taxonomy's term with post

```
$post_id = wp_insert_post($new_post);
$taxonomy = 'user_r_category';
$termObj  = get_term_by( 'id', 7, $taxonomy);
wp_set_object_terms($post_id, $termObj, $taxonomy);
```

Comment: Thanks. This is working for me: wp_set_object_terms($post_id, array(7), $taxonomy);
It is NOT working with $termObj  = get_term_by( 'id', 7, $taxonomy);
Do you have an idea why?

Comment: I don't know why! but `docs` do not state that the second parameter should be array. Well you made it . appreciate :)

Answer (score 2):

You can do it directly when inserting your post, with tax_input parameter :

```
$post = array(
    'post_title'    => $my_sanitized_title,
    'post_content'  => $my_sanitized_text,
    'post_status'   => 'publish',
    'post_type'     => 'post',
    'tax_input'    => array(
        'hierarchical_tax' => array($my_hierarchical_tax_id)
    ),
);
$post_id = wp_insert_post($post);
```

This is an array. See the doc for detailed parameters : https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_post/

Comment: As mentioned [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/83158/87622) the `wp_insert_post` function internally checks for a user capability, so it will ignore the taxonomy terms if this is used in an automated way, via cron for example. `wp_set_object_terms` is more robust.