# Assign wordpress custom taxonomy category into custom post type

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, custom-taxonomy

I've been working for a custom form that insert post into custom post type in wordpress. I need to assign a custom taxonomy categories with this post.

Here is the custom taxonomy registered -

```php
// Portfolio Category
$portfolio_cat_tax = array(
    'name' => 'Portfolio Category',
    'singular_name' => 'Portfolio Category',
    'search_items' => 'Search Category',
    'all_items' => 'All Category',
    'edit_item' => 'Edit Category',
    'update_item' => 'Update Category',
    'add_new_item' => 'Add New Category',
    'new_item_name' => 'New Category',
    'menu_name' => 'Portfolio Category',
);

$portfolio_cat_tax_args = array(
    'hierarchical' => true,
    'labels' => $portfolio_cat_tax,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'show_admin_column' => true,
    'query_var' => 'portfolio_category',
    'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'portfolio-category'),
);

register_taxonomy('portfolio_category', 'portfolio', $portfolio_cat_tax_args);
```

Here is the custom post type registered -

```php
// Portfolio post type
$khs_portfolio_labels = array(
    'name'                  => __( 'Portfolio', 'khs' ),
    'singular_name'         => __( 'Portfolio', 'khs' ),
    'menu_name'             => __( 'Portfolio', 'khs' ),
    'name_admin_bar'        => __( 'Portfolio', 'khs' ),
    'add_new'               => __( 'Add Portfolio', 'khs' ),
    'add_new_item'          => __( 'New Portfolio', 'khs' ),
    'new_item'              => __( 'New Portfolio', 'khs' ),
    'edit_item'             => __( 'Edit Portfolio', 'khs' ),
);

$khs_portfolio_args = array(
    'labels'             => $khs_portfolio_labels,
    'public'             => true,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'show_ui'            => true,
    'show_in_menu'       => true,
    'query_var'          => true,
    'rewrite'            => array( 'slug' => 'portfolio' ),
    'has_archive'        => false,
    'hierarchical'       => true,
    'menu_icon'          => 'dashicons-portfolio',
    'menu_position'      => null,
    'supports'           => array( 'title', 'thumbnail' ),
    'taxonomies' => array('portfolio_category'),
    
);

register_post_type('portfolio', $khs_portfolio_args);
```

Here is the form data submission code that I've tried -

```php
// Handle Submit Portfolio
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST" && isset($_POST["agency_portfolio_submit"])) {
    $khs_project_name = sanitize_text_field($_POST["project_name"]);
    $khs_portfolio_category = $_POST["selected_agency_portfolio_category"];
    $khs_portfolio_link = sanitize_text_field($_POST["portfolio_link"]);

    // Insert the post
    $khs_portfolio_post = array(
        'post_title'    => $khs_project_name,
        'post_status'   => 'publish',
        'post_author'   => get_current_user_id(),
        'post_type'     => 'portfolio',
        'meta_input'    => [
            'portfolio_link'  => $khs_portfolio_link,
            'selected_agency_portfolio_category'    =>  $khs_portfolio_category
        ],
        'tax_input'     => array(
            'portfolio_category' => $khs_portfolio_category,
        ),
    );

    $khs_portfolio_post_id = wp_insert_post($khs_portfolio_post);
    wp_set_object_terms($khs_portfolio_post_id, $khs_portfolio_category, "portfolio-category");

    // Handle the thumbnail upload
    if ($_FILES['portfolio_thumbnail']['size'] > 0) {
        require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php');
        require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php');
        require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/media.php');
        
        $attachment_id = media_handle_upload('portfolio_thumbnail', $khs_portfolio_post_id);
        set_post_thumbnail($khs_portfolio_post_id, $attachment_id);
    }
}
```

I've tried with `tax_input`, `wp_set_object_terms`, `wp_set_post_terms` but it's not working for me. `$khs_portfolio_category` is returning an array of taxonomy ids.

Is there any mess with custom post type and custom taxonomy capabilities or something else?

I've also tried some stackoverflow and it's relevant network site here -

[StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42110516/wp-insert-post-with-custom-taxonomy)

[Wordpress StackExchange](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/173618/why-cant-i-add-a-custom-post-type-to-a-custom-taxonomy)

But it's not assigning the taxonomy category to the post.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use action hooks to sequence each registration.
2. Sequence `register_taxonomy()` to execute before `register_post_type()`.
3. When calling `register_taxonomy()`, set the `$post_type` argument to *null*

---

## Use action hooks

For example, the assignment to `$portfolio_cat_tax` and `$portfolio_cat_tax_args` and the call to `register_taxonomy()` should all be contained within a function. This function acts as a handler to the `init` action hook. The action hook must have the priority set for `register_taxonomy()` to execute before `register_post_type()`.

### Example:

```
// Portfolio Category
function register_my_custom_taxonomy() {
    $portfolio_cat_tax = array(
        'name' => 'Portfolio Category',
        'singular_name' => 'Portfolio Category',
        'search_items' => 'Search Category',
        'all_items' => 'All Category',
        'edit_item' => 'Edit Category',
        'update_item' => 'Update Category',
        'add_new_item' => 'Add New Category',
        'new_item_name' => 'New Category',
        'menu_name' => 'Portfolio Category',
    );

    $portfolio_cat_tax_args = array(
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'labels' => $portfolio_cat_tax,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'show_admin_column' => true,
        'query_var' => 'portfolio_category',
        'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'portfolio-category'),
    );

    register_taxonomy('portfolio_category', null, $portfolio_cat_tax_args);
}
add_action( 'init', 'register_my_custom_taxonomy', 10 );
```

```
// Portfolio post type
function register_my_custom_post_type() {
    $khs_portfolio_labels = array(
        'name'                  => __( 'Portfolio', 'khs' ),
        'singular_name'         => __( 'Portfolio', 'khs' ),
        'menu_name'             => __( 'Portfolio', 'khs' ),
        'name_admin_bar'        => __( 'Portfolio', 'khs' ),
        'add_new'               => __( 'Add Portfolio', 'khs' ),
        'add_new_item'          => __( 'New Portfolio', 'khs' ),
        'new_item'              => __( 'New Portfolio', 'khs' ),
        'edit_item'             => __( 'Edit Portfolio', 'khs' ),
    );

    $khs_portfolio_args = array(
        'labels'             => $khs_portfolio_labels,
        'public'             => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'show_ui'            => true,
        'show_in_menu'       => true,
        'query_var'          => true,
        'rewrite'            => array( 'slug' => 'portfolio' ),
        'has_archive'        => false,
        'hierarchical'       => true,
        'menu_icon'          => 'dashicons-portfolio',
        'menu_position'      => null,
        'supports'           => array( 'title', 'thumbnail' ),
        'taxonomies' => array('portfolio_category'),
        
    );

    register_post_type('portfolio', $khs_portfolio_args);
}
add_action( 'init', 'register_my_custom_post_type', 20 );
```

Comment: Tried with your suggested code. But it also not assigning the taxonomy category with the post.

Comment: Does everything else save successfully except for the custom taxonomy term(s)?

Comment: Yes. Everything is saved successfully. But not the taxonomy terms.

Comment: I tried the code, and it works for me without the call to `wp_set_object_terms`. What value (as an example) is retrieved for `$khs_portfolio_category` from the HTML form? Have you confirmed the value is an array with valid `portfolio_category` IDs? Can you check the `wp_term_relationships` database table to see if anything at all is saved to the database for the new portfolio post? Have you tried creating a *portfolio* post and manually adding *portfolio_categories*? If so, did this work? Could you please post your code for the HTML form? Is the HTML form on a post? a page? a portfolio page?

Comment: On what kind of page are the calls to `add_action()` and the action handler functions? Theme functions.php? Child theme functions.php? Plugin page? Template page? If you can successfully add *portfolio_categories* manually to *portfolio* posts, the problem might be with the HTML form itself or the script that tries to retrieve the submitted value. Is the *enctype="multipart/form-data"* attribute set on the `<form>` tag? Are you using any plugins that could interfere (e.g. using hooks) with saving taxonomy terms to posts?

Comment: Nothing is being saved at ```wp_term_relationships``` DB table and yes I've received valid taxonomy terms IDs from my html form that returns to ```$khs_portfolio_category```. I've also tried to add terms manually and yes it has been saved. But on form submit, it's not being saved. 

I've called ```add_action``` on my theme functions.php and it's not plugin. I'm trying to assign terms data from a ```page template``` and there is no plugin I'm using since my theme development that could interfere to save terms as well.

Comment: Try adding `'show_in_rest' => true` to the list of options in `$portfolio_cat_tax_args`. (Since it was not originally there, how did you add terms manually?) Also, use only `wp_insert_post()` for now, not `wp_set_object_terms()`. It will be easier to see where the problem is. Just to confirm `$khs_portfolio_category` is not the problem, try replacing it with a literal array like: `array( <term_id> )` as the value for the key `'portfolio_category'` in the `tax_input` array. This is to confirm that <term_id> is submitted as an integer, not a string. When testing are you logged in as admin?

Comment: Actually, the problem was I was submitted the form from another file and require it to ```functions.php``` file. After calling it from my form template file instead of ```functions.php```, now everything is working fine. Thanks for your time guys. It was form submission file calling issue. LOL

Comment: Great. Glad you found the problem.